# Prove that inequality $AM \cdot AN + BM \cdot BN + CM \cdot CN \geq DM \cdot DN$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $ABCD$ be the regular tetrahedron, and $M, N$ points in space. Prove that: $$AM \cdot AN + BM \cdot BN + CM \cdot CN \geq DM \cdot DN$$

Maybe use [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality)
solve it?

Comment: Give Cartesian coordinates $A=(1, -1, -1), B=(-1, 1, -1), C=(-1, -1, 1), D=(1, 1, 1), M=(x, y, z), N=(a,b,c)$ then it's proving $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{((x-1)^2+(y+1)^2+(z+1)^2)((a-1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2)} \ge \sqrt{((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2)((a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2)}$

Comment: Let $M=B$ and $N=C$ (or circular) then we have equality:$$AM \cdot AN + BM \cdot BN + CM \cdot CN = DM \cdot DN$$

Comment: You also obtain equality if $M=N=\frac{A+B+C-D}{2}$

Comment: Indeed, this is just Ptolemy's inequality. See my solution. You have to be a little subtle in the application though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes this is just Ptolemy's inequality.

Suppose that the isometry (i.e. rotation/reflection) swapping $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ sends $M$ to $L$. Now it suffices to show that $$BL\cdot AN+AL\cdot BN+DL\cdot CN\geq CL\cdot DN.$$ Ptolemy's inequality gives the following: $$\begin{align*}BL\cdot AN+AL\cdot BN&\geq LN\cdot AB\\LN\cdot CD+DL\cdot CN&\geq CL\cdot DN.\end{align*}$$ Since $AB=CD$, adding the two gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Very, very nice. Using this and the fact that Ptolemy's inequality is an equality only if the four points are coplanar and concyclic, one can show that equality is attained exactly in the cases mentioned in the comments above: either $M=N=\frac{A+B+C-D}{2}$ or $M\ne N$ and $\{M,N\}\subset \{A,B,C\}$.